# How does adobe create functional tests for applications like Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, acceptance-testing

We have a really interactive web application. There are a significant amount of interactions. Here are a few examples:

- being able to add objects to the canvas
- camera controls for zooming and panning
- drag + spacebar = panning the camera
- keyboard shortcuts
- help menus
- popover tooltips on first load explaining various features
- focus edit mode of specific objects
- context menus
- and MORE

Now with this sort of application you can create unit tests to your hearts content; however, both integration tests and webdriver/selenium style tests are needed to confirm that your application is actually working.

The problem I'm running in to is that webdriver is a bit too clunky, slow to develop in, and doesn't really make it easy to test things like `drag + spacebar = panning the camera`. Likely, there is a better tool out there that can help us catch real bugs before they go out while also being a joy to develop with. There may also be some other testing style that I don't know about.

Ideas? Tips?